# ACPI errors prevent boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, startup, acpi, initramfs

I have HP 840 with Ubuntu 18.04. On startup, I received the following message.

```
ACPI Error: Field CAP1 at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 disk) (20170831/dsopcode-235)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed  \_SB._OSC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831-550) 

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

There were not any updates done recently. I was trying to find possible solutions but, unfortunately, did not succeed. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: kernel-5.4.7 should have this fixed according to bug reports

Answer (score 0):

have you tried booting with parameters such as nomodeset noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll and see if anything changes? You can press E in grub to get into editing mode.